# How can I have a static img next to a box with changing text (carousel)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I want to have a red box with changing text (like a carousel)  along with a static img. Also, I want the carousel be hidden on sm and xs devices.

But the carousel does not fill the whole div, just appears like a tiny banner. Also, there is a big space between the carousel and img. I am doing something wrong?
Here is the code that Used:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="col-md-4  carousel slide col-lg-4  hidden-sm hidden-xs text-center" data-ride="carousel"
         style="background-color: #C33233">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner carousel-overlay text-center">
      <div class="item active">
        DISCOVER THE MIRACLE OF DATA .....                
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        text 222222                
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
    <img src="./img/homepage_pics/ddi.png" alt="Data">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey, has my answer here helped at all?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the height of your carousel, you can give it a class and use this CSS to your needs.

```
.carousel .item {
  height: <size in px, em, etc.>;
  background-color: #C33233;
}
```

You have a `</div>` that closes your `carousel-inner` too soon.

You can also remove `col-lg-4` as the sizing option `md` is a responsive class, it will be effective on all screen sizes.